# Is this an error in Java's A beginner's guide 7th Edition

Tags: java

Found this in Java's Seventh Edition Beginner Book (Java SE 9 btw.) but do-while-while doesn't make too much sense and causes compilation errors.
Look at this piece of code from the book (very much shortened):

[image]

As a solution I just compressed all conditions into the first while but wondered if it was possible to use book version?

[lol full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WV5R.png)

[Took the picture with my phone so sorry for quality, full picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykIJu.jpg)

Comment: The code snippet looks incomplete. So it's hard to say if the error is in the book or happened during the shortening.

Comment: Are you sure those aren't 2 do-while loops and you just cut of the first `do {` ?

Comment: Thx, yeah seemed weird

Comment: No sure of it ill send full pic if you want

Comment: Sucks that I can't embed images... only links lol anyway here is the line before, see no do's

Comment: Please post the shortened code

Comment: The code in the picture is incomplete. If you can upload the whole part.

Comment: I have this book and your code is incomplete... [HERE](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=hMKjAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA90&lpg=PA90&dq=while(ignore+!%3D+%27%5Cn%27);&source=bl&ots=BmjNUpqJLw&sig=lefjmrFLIlxwOcAdikqlU-lsZow&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZnrS04YnaAhVFPo8KHcG3B8AQ6AEIOTAB#v=onepage&q=while(ignore%20!%3D%20'%5Cn')%3B&f=false) is the full page with two nested `do-while` loops. It uses two a nested `do-while` so code is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

In response to watchme: My simple and unconditionally simplistic solution.
This was my solution (not very pretty):

```
char choice = (char) System.in.read();
while(choice == '\n' & choice != '1' & choice != '2' & choice != '3' & choice != '4' & choice != '5' & choice != '6' & choice != '7' & choice != 'q')choice = (char) System.in.read();
```